# Simple interest equated monthly installments while borrowing then paying back

Tags: sequences-and-series

What is the formula for calculating equated monthly installments with simple interest? How can one derive it?

Comment: You need to specify the question better. Are you borrowing money and paying it back, or depositing to an account and asking what it is worth after some number of periods?

Comment: Yes . for borrowing and then pay back

Answer (score 1):

Note that interest on a loan is not usually specified as simple or compound.  You borrow some amount.  After one period, you make a payment, which pays the interest due for that period plus some of the principal.  The next period, you make another payment, which pays that period's interest (less, because the principal is lower) and some more principal.  It is, in effect, compound interest.

In a usual level payment loan, the formula is $$A=\frac {Pr(1+r)^n}{(1+r)^n-1}$$
where $$A=payment\\P=initial principal\\r=interest per period\\n=number of periods$$

The derivation comes from summing the geometric series of the value of the payments.  You should be able to find it with a bit of searching.